Cannot access html element via selenium and python
[EDITED]
I want to access a html element via selenium.
Here is my code:
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABBV/analysis'
print('############# Kursziel (via Yahoo)')

val_price_target = '999999.'

print("URL (yahoo):",url)

# grab price target from webpage
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
average_price = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.label.average > span.price")
val_price_target = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(average_price)).text
print("Value: ", val_price_target)

xPath is set like in the comments below.
The element I search for is Average (from Research Analysis->Analyst Price Targets).
The code here is simplified for example.
The full code iterates over an excel (as pandas dataframe), tries to find some stocks and if the data is missing there (exception call), this code is called.
I get this error:
############# Kursziel (via Yahoo)
URL (yahoo): https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABBV/analysis
Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Projects\Python_Projekt_ACN_intern\Code\Yahoo-Problem_fullcode.py", line 109, in get_price_target
result_string = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath_string))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
                
File "C:\Users\eduard.szilaghi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace: GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61EB31572+60802]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61EAAAC72]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61E967CE4]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61E9B6D4D]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61E9B6E1C]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61E9FCE37]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61E9DABBF]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61E9FA224]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61E9DA923]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61E9A8FEC]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61E9A9C21]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61EE3420D+3217949]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61EE761A7+3488183]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61EE6F12F+3459391]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF61EBEB936+823622]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61EAB600F]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61EAB0F34]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61EAB10C2]
(No symbol) [0x00007FF61EAA1914]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFA475F257D+29]
RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFA48FAAA48+40]


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Projects\Python_Projekt_ACN_intern\Code\Yahoo-Problem_fullcode.py", line 386, in <module>
pt_val, pt_cur = get_price_target(isin)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Projects\Python_Projekt_ACN_intern\Code\Yahoo-Problem_fullcode.py", line 124, in get_price_target
val_price_target = get_price_target_yahoo(uscode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "c:\Projects\Python_Projekt_ACN_intern\Code\Yahoo-Problem_fullcode.py", line 84, in get_price_target_yahoo
val_price_target = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(average_price)).text
                   
File "C:\Users\eduard.szilaghi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 105, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

At the first try it worked (looked like in the comments below). Now I get this TimeOut exception. If I try to access the xpath element from dev tools console, I cannot find it.
Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

I can't find any element on the page using that XPath expression. Which element are you trying to locate and access on the website?

@Shawn: Research Analysis->Analyst Price Targets->Average
(on 7. May 2024 at 4:24 PM it is 183.20 USD)

Remove the try-except, run it again, capture the full error message as text, and come back and edit your question and post the error message. Eating all exceptions is not a good practice and can lead you into situations like this where you can't figure out what's going on when the error message would point you straight to where the issue is.

You can get this value using the CSS selector,
div.label.average > span.price

You can put this into your (updated) code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABBV/analysis"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

average_price = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.label.average > span.price")

print('############# Kursziel (via Yahoo)')
print("URL (yahoo):", url)
print("Average Price locator (yahoo):", average_price)
raw_res = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(average_price)).text
print("Raw res (yahoo): ", raw_res)

and it prints
############# Kursziel (via Yahoo)
URL (yahoo): https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/ABBV/analysis
Average Price locator (yahoo): ('css selector', 'div.label.average > span.price')
Raw res (yahoo):  183.20


You need to get rid of Accept/Reject cookies pop-up after the URL is launched, else selenium may not locate the targeted element.

@Shawn I've run this code several times and never received the cookies popup that you are referring to. I'm not sure what to tell you.

Ah ok, then no worries. Each time I launched the URL I always get the cookies pop-up. May be its region specific(My hunch).
